# Getting byte size of a c++ struct given as a string

Tags: c++, dynamic, compilation

I have the following problem. I am given a string. This string represents a valid c++ struct.

I need to figure out the fastest way to get the size in bytes of this struct.

The most obvious approach to me is:

Write struct to a file and turn that file into a script that writes the size to a file, call a compiler from the system, compile the file, run the executable, parse the file.

This is absurd, there has to be a better way.

I have heard about GCC's JITC library, that might be a better approach. But since I don;t need full blown compilation there might be a simpler way?

The struct is represented as it would in native c++ code, i.e. I have this string

> "struct MySstruct {
> int field1;
> void* field2;
> short field3;
> };"

Would be the content of the string.

Comment: whats wrong with `the_string.size()` ?

Comment: That's the size of the string, not the byte size of the struct being represented by the string.

For example `int myverylongvarnam = 0;` doesn;t have the same size as an int.

Comment: @Makogan You haven't described how you represent the struct as a string, so we cannot answer your question.

Comment: the question is unclear. If the string is a representation of say `my_struct` then the size of the struct is `sizeof(my_struct)` and that is independent of the size of the representation

Comment: I'm not sure why you say you'd need to `...parse the file`.  Use the string to generate a `C++` executable that outputs `sizeof(generated_struct)`.  Or have I misread this?

Comment: That should be a difficult problem since you need to know how to parse C++ code. When given the string `"struct S { int k; };"` the parsing should be easy. When the string is `"struct S1 { int k; }; struct S2 { S1 s; }; struct S3 { S2 s; };"` and you need the size of `S3`, well... it's more complicated. Consider now the case of members being `std::vector<T>` where `T` is a non-trivial type... I think writing the string into a file and then calling a compiler on it should be the easiest way (though not the best).

Comment: I'd do a scons script that compiles your struct and outputs sizeof.

Comment: I'm afraid 'the compiler' is most likely the best tool for the job, because it does all that heavy lifting for you. As llualpu already said, all is fine and dandy as long as you've got POD objects in your struct. But as soon as you get into classes or even custom types...

Comment: Is there a way to call the compiler as a library? Because writing and reading to disk is going to make this operation chug a lot.